# .htaccess redirecting dynamic URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic-url

I am using the following code to *attempt* to redirect a dynamic URL to a new dynamic URL, under the same domain:

```
RewriteRule ^products/item/^\d([^/]+) /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I've tried these too:

```
RewriteRule ^products/item/[^\d]([^/]+) /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/item/[0-9]([^/]+) /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But this was redirecting `/products/item/342/` to `/product/42/`, I tested this on a larger number (e.g. 123456789) and it redirected to `/product/23456789/`.

It would appear that my rule is not picking up the firsts digit, can anyone help me resolve this?

I've also tried using `[\d]` instaled of `[0-9]`, but this has the same problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^products/item/(\d[^/]+) /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this was the group in the regexp that caused problem. 
$1 will match all which is within parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^products/item/([0-9]+) /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
```